# How To Write Regex to Extract URL from Bing Search Result?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this to extract URL from google search result
(https://www.google.com/search?q=myquery&num=100)

```
@"(?<=<h3 class=\""r\""><a href=\""\/url\?q=)(.*?)(?=&amp;)";
```

Here's my code to extract URL from google search result

```
const string regexPattern = @"(?<=<h3 class=\""r\""><a href=\""\/url\?q=)(.*?)(?=&amp;)";

public static string[] TopUrls(string data)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern);
        MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(data);
        return collection.Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray();
    }

string downloadUrl = "https://www.google.com" + "/search?q=" + keyword.ToString() + "&num=" + numResults + "&as_qdr=all&ei=LrUVVf7UMrPfsAS7lICgCw&sa=N&biw=1440&bih=690";
                fetch.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Host, "www.google.com");
                string data = fetch.DownloadString(downloadUrl);
                string[] results = TopUrls(data);
```

from that code i can extract each URL from google search result.

Here's the result:
https : //www blogger com/ profile/ 15582992268736301561
https : //www blogger com/ profile /17377873899922361640

How to write regex for this URL?
http://www.bing.com/search?q=myquery&count=100

Thank You :)

Comment: I need to extract each URL from search result, for example https://sourceforge.net/projects/myquery/files/myquery

Comment: I think you want to use a regex to parse html.

Comment: Do you already test that regex for google search?

Comment: yes, i've already tested, i've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this `<h2>*?<a\s+[^>]*?href="([^"]*)"`

Comment: I fix the answer, can you try this one?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Bing Search API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/search/)s? If you really must parse the HTML, you're looking for algo results. Get the **li** tags with **b_algo** class and extract the URL from them.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to use:

```
<cite>(.*?)</cite>
```

Then you need another regex to remove `<strong>` tags